# iphone uiButton release

Tags: iphone, uibutton, release

Sir,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
   playButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(curLocX,1.0,45,kScrollObjHeight)];
    [playButton   setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [playButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(playClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  curLocX+=100;
   }}
```

I have release the playButton in viewDidUnload and dealloc 
   1.I have created four buttons but I released only one time its right or wrong
   2.I have released viewDidUnload and dealloc its right or wrong 
Advance Thanks for your valuable suggestions 
  Suresh.M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, if an object has been allocated 4 times, it should be released by the same number of count.

btw am not sure what are you trying to do here, at the end of the loop playButton will only have reference to the last object and you are not even adding your playButton as a subview to any view. Anyways you can avoid using the alloc and user buttonWithType method, this method itself handles the alloc and release of UIButton object so you don't have to worry about the release call.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(curLocX,1.0,45,kScrollObjHeight);
    [playButton   setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [playButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(playClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    curLocX+=100;
    [self.view addSubview: playButton]; //you might have missed this statement
```

}}

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. Before It self I added the subview. The problem is alloc only .

Answer (score 0):

you should remove your button release from at least one of the places (viewDidUnload/dealloc) to avoid dubble release getting called for an object.

creating objects (in your case buttons) and releasing all of them at one time is fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to release the button in the **for** loop itself.

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
       playButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(curLocX,1.0,45,kScrollObjHeight)];
        [playButton   setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [playButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(playClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       curLocX+=100;
       [playButton release];
       }
```

NOTE:
If you allocated an object 'n' times you have to release the object 'n' times.